# AEM 6.5.6/Day CQ Linkchecker + Handlebars: a/link tag is getting stripped

Tags: aem, aem-6

As above. When I looked at the rendered HTML, the a/link tag is missing completely.

This is my HTML code:

```
<h3>{{PRODUCT_CATEGORY}}</h3>
<h3><a href="{{PRODUCT_URL}}" x-cq-linkchecker=“valid”>MY LINK HERE</a></h3>
```

I looked at the logs and it's because of the linkchecker service

```
com.day.cq.rewriter.linkchecker.impl.LinkCheckerImpl Ignoring malformed URI
```

This should not be a problem (theoretically) because I followed all the 3 suggestions on this page: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-cloud-kcs/kbarticles/KA-16563.html?lang=en

- I added x-cq-linkchecker=“valid” in my link tag. As a test, I tried "valid" and "skip". I got the same result.
- I disabled link checking in Day CQ Link Checker Transformer service

[image]

- Added ^ to the Link checker override patterns
  [image]

Comment: What is the link format/pattern? Disabling the link checker service should've enough, and the logs are saying that is precisely being ignored, so, maybe the XSS (Antisamy) is doing the filtering, can you check the logs for Antisamy warnings/errors?

Comment: Did you try to add a proper context in the anchor? Something like href="{{PRODUCT_URL @ context='uri'}}" ?